# In Hotmail, can I forward an email I've received as an attachment?

Tags: outlook.com

Does Hotmail let me forward an email as an attachment? When I try forward an email it reformats the contents and puts greater=than signs in front of every line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you can't really do that via Hotmail, but there are workarounds to avoid adding the `>` in front of every line, if that's your only concern.

You can [import](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/static.py?page=guide.cs&guide=25413&topic=25415&answer=164640) your mails into a Gmail account and forward them from there in a better format. You can also choose the `From` to be your Hotmail account so people won't be confused on who is that *Bernhard Hofmann* with a different mail than usual.

Comment: You could also press this little up button.. since I guess this answer was helpful :)

Answer (score 3):

I guess you cannot send an email as an attachment unless you use a desktop email client which lets you save it as an attachment.